# Mex type for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 and R2007b

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

i want to use mex type for vs2008 and matlab2007b.i tried code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <matrix.h>
#include<mex.h>
using namespace std;
void hello(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  mexPrintf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

and get this error

```
'matrix.h': No such file or directory
```

and i wrote below in matlab commond win

```
mex -setup
Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2007b\sys\lcc 

[0] None 

Compiler:
```

so what is should do to use mex type?

thanks

Comment: I am assuming you choose the [1] option. Most likely your compiler doesnt know where matrix.h is located , you may need to tune it somehow in linking properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You don't need to include `<matrix.h>`, `<matrix.h>` is included inside `<mex.h>`. Try: `include "mex.h"` instead of `<mex.h>`, and remove `include <matrix.h>`.
2. `mex -setup` could not locate your Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 compiler.

The selection menu should look as follows:

`Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files:`

`Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y`

`Select a compiler:`
`[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2007b\sys\lcc`
`[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008`
`[0] None`

Since Visual 2008 is newer than Matlab R2007b, Matlab can't automatically locate Visual 2008.

There is a way to add it manually.
Refer here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297616

Please consider: I could not fully verify the following instructions because I don't have Matlab R2007b:

**Step by step instructions:**

1. Go to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18508-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-mex-and-mbuild-setup-files
2. Download the zip file VS2008Matlab.zip (press the "Download zip" blue button on the top right side of the page).
3. Extract the zip file.
4. Copy folder content VS2008MATLABMexCompilerFilesX64 to: `C:\Program Files\MATALB\R2007b\bin\win64\mexopts` (assuming your version is 64 bit in default installation folder).
5. Copy folder content VS2008MATLABMBuildCompilerFilesX64 to: `C:\Program Files\MATALB\R2007b\bin\win64\msbuildopts`
6. Execute `mex -setup`, and verify Visual Studio 2008 is in the list.

Comment: i downloaded vs 2005 but still when i run it i get ' fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mex.h': No such file or directory'

Comment: and i studied that link before posting here but didn't get soultion, can you give step by stepl solution to me here?

Comment: I edited my answer - add Step by step instructions. I could not fully verify instructions. Please notify me if it works.

Comment: thanks dear.actually i tried these all options but i did mistake, i didn't copied file in matlab\bin directory therefore , it give error" hello.cpp cannot find", now i tried it and it works,bingo.