# How to create .mex file with Parallel Studio XE 2015 and Matlab 2012a?

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I use Matlab 2012a while the Fortran compiler is VS2013 + Intel® Visual Fortran x15 in Windows 10. Unfortunately，my MATLAB version does not support my Intel Visual Fortran Composer  for Fortran along with VS 2013. Is there a way I can edit the mex options so MATLAB recognizes the new compilers? Or do I **have to** move to the latest Matlab version（undesirable)？

One [closely related thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/156878-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2015-for-fortran) on Matlab user support forum raised my hope to resolve this problem, but I don't quite understand how to adjust the xml file to my Fortran compiler (the compiler's path has already been added to the environment path). Could someone kindly explain the procedure in details?

Comment: You can probably solve it by using kind of solution like I posted here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583411/mex-type-for-microsoft-visual-c-2008-and-r2007b/38589532#38589532)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583411/mex-type-for-microsoft-visual-c-2008-and-r2007b/38589532#38589532]. You may have to edit XML file manually...

Comment: Use tag fortran for all Fortran questions to get more views.

Comment: @Rotem,thank you for providing the link. I searched on the mathwork file exchange website, but find no mex setting file for Intel Fortran XE2015. There are some files for vs2013+CPP but not for fortran. You mentioned edit XML file manually, can you elaborate on this, or provide some useful tutorial? Thank you.

Comment: I found something here: [https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/414abe0b2a6002cd8945](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/414abe0b2a6002cd8945)